# Combine Safari browser detection and .on('change', function () using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My aim is to fix a Safari bug (centering of select box text not working) using jQuery and CSS. It works perfectly when the page loads the first time. This is the code I wrote - some mix between jQuery and plain JavaScript but it does the job:

HTML:

```
<div class="selectbox">
    <select name="filter1" id="selector">
       <option value="option1">Jackets</option>
       <option value="option2">Shoes</option>
       <option value="option3">Trouseres</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1)  {
       $(document).ready(function() {
          if(document.getElementById('selector').value=='option1') {
             $(".selectbox").addClass("opt1");
          }
          else if(document.getElementById('selector').value=='option2') {
             $(".selectbox").addClass("opt2");
          }
          else {
             $(".selectbox").addClass("opt3");
          }
       });
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
/* This positions the select option text in Safari */
.selectbox.opt1 select {
    padding-left: 44px!important;
}
.selectbox.opt2 select {
    padding-left: 35px!important;
}
.selectbox.opt3 select {
    padding-left: 51px!important;
}
```

If Safari is detected, some additional class name is added to the div class "selectbox" - depending on the value selected in the select box. I can then format each composite class independently in CSS using padding-left and this allows me to center select box text of different length.

Now I would like to get this working also upon selectbox select change, and this is what I tried in Javascript:

```
var selectvar = 'False';
    $(document).ready(function() {
       if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
                selectvar = 'True';
        }
    };    

$("#selector").on("change", function () {
    if((document.getElementById('selector').value=='option1') && selectvar = 'True') {
        $(".selectbox").addClass("opt1");
    }
    else if((document.getElementById('selector').value=='option2') && selectvar = 'True') {
        $(".selectbox").addClass("opt2");
    }
    else if((document.getElementById('selector').value=='option3') && slctspc = 'True') {
        $(".selectbox").addClass("opt3");
    }
});
```

This doesn't work. I know it would be good to provide a jsfiddle, but my Safari browser is too old to run the fiddle (or blocks it). I hope the issue still becomes clear from looking at my code sample. Thank you for any help!

EDIT: Pure CSS solutions like using "text-align: -webkit-center;" do NOT work for all Safari versions - this is why I am using JavaScript and it does solve the problem. The issue is to combine my code with ".on('change', function ()"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-align is not working on safari <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182559/text-align-is-not-working-on-safari-select)

Comment: No, not a duplicate. This post uses "text-align: -webkit-center;" in CSS - I did test this and it is not working, which can also be read below this post. Maybe it does work for some Safari versions, but definitely not for all. Javascript is the solution, since my first code example (the one with $(document).ready(function() {) does work.

Comment: You used `=` to compare, but it's `==`. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h2uyncov/

Comment: Thank you - I will implement and test it to see if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code some:

**selectvar** is now boolean, no need for an if statement

If you will be adding classes to the parent div, you might need to remove the old ones. So that is what `removeClass` is doing. This is probably the problem.

No need to mix vanilla and jQuery so I'm using `$(this).val()` and I made a few other misc small changes to clean it up.

I also added a data attribute to each option that way there is no need for a bunch of `if` `else if` statements.

```
<div class="selectbox">
    <select name="filter1" id="selector">
       <option data-class="opt1" value="option1">Jackets</option>
       <option data-class="opt2" value="option2">Shoes</option>
       <option data-class="opt3" value="option3">Trouseres</option>
    </select>
</div>


var selectvar = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1);        

$("#selector").on("change", function () {
    $(".selectbox").removeClass().addClass("selectbox");

    if(selectvar) {
        $(".selectbox").addClass($(this).data("class"));
    }
});
```